# Having difficulty to input file as prompt "$" dissapears in Unix

Tags: linux

I am using Linux for the first time to run a fluent file.

I created an input file.

**Code:**

```
(set! *cx-exit-on-error* #t)
rc fluent.cas
it 100
wd fluent.dat
exit
yes
or 
rcd fluent1.cas
it 100
wcd fluent2.dat
exit
yes
```

After the final line the prompt **"$"** disappears. Hence I can't input anything. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the spawned process (whatever that actually is here) has not returned.

Comment: What is this input file? How are you running it?

Comment: What language?  Please [edit] your question to add tags to indicate the language you're using and to explain how you're running this.

Comment: I am using CentOS . It is a linux based system.